# ExtJS store add calls both create and destroy

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
                this.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields: [
                    'id',
                    'name',
                    'Address',
                    'status',
                ],
                autoLoad: auto,
                autoSync: auto,
                remoteSort: true,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    api: {
                        create: '../../create.php',
                        read: '../../read.php',
                        destroy: '../../destroy.php',
                        update: '../../update.php'
                    },
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: '__data',
                        totalProperty: 'grandTotal'
                    },
                    writer: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: '__data'
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        exception: function( t, response, op ) {
                            var _da = Ext.decode( response.responseText );
                            if( _da ) {
                                if( _da.message == "ExistingName" ) {
                                    _da.message = Locale.gettext('name already exists');
                                    } else {
                                        frm = _self.subnetEditor.down('form');
                                        name_field = frm.down('textfield[name=name]');
                                    }
                                    name_field.markInvalid(Locale.gettext(_da.message));
                                }
                                showMsg( _da.success, _da.message );
                                if( op.action == 'create' || op.action == 'update' ) {
                                    _self.store.rejectChanges();
                                    _self.store.load();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is the store that calls four php files to do the CRUD, and some listener to process the duplicate name.

```
        removeSelected: function() {
        var _self = this;
        Ext.Msg.show( {
            title: Locale.gettext( 'Remove selected?' ),
            msg: Locale.gettext( 'Are you sure you want to remove ALL SELECTED items?' ),
            icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING,
            buttons: Ext.Msg.OKCANCEL,
            buttonAlign: 'right',
            fn: function( button ) {
                if( button == 'ok' ) {
                    var grid = _self.down( 'grid' );
                    if( grid ) {
                        var selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                        if( selection.length ) {
                            _self.store.remove( selection );
                            if( _self.useGridRowEditing ) {
                                _self.store.sync();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } );
    }
```

Here is the remove function will remove the selected items, and I have store.add(item) to add records. But the problem is if I run the remove function, and then store.add to add any items, the store.add will fire create and destroy together. The second destroy will post exact data as the first time when I run the remove function.
I suppose that the store.add will only call the create api in the proxy, but why destroy has been called?

I see the remove throws an exception. If an exception has been thrown, is that mean the remove action is still pending? So it batch the add and remove together?

Comment: Remember that sync() will batch together any pending actions on the store. So if you've added 2 records, removed 1 and updated 3, calling sync() will batch these together

Comment: @existdissolve Shouldn't the autosync execute the remove after the remove is called? If so, I do the add after remove, it should be only one add action left. In my case, I run 1 remove, and then run 1 add, I see it calls destroy on the remove, create and destroy on the add.

Comment: Are any errors happening when sending the requests to the server? And can you post the code that does the add() bits?

Comment: Yes, the remove action always throws an exception: '{"__data":[null],"success":true,"message":"Remove successful","total":1}', does this cause it pending? It's weird, my PHP return nothing on the remove, but it get '[null]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not caused by the ExtJS, it causes the server respond "[null]". The array of null is considered as an exception, I guess the exception causes the request becomes pending.

Comment: To be precise - this is an array with the first element equal to null.
It may cause a havoc, because it's not the data that is expected.

Comment: @Thevs I think you are right. To fulfill my curiosity, what does the 'havoc' mean?

Comment: I meant that it is not in a format of your `fields` property. The 'havoc' means just any unexpected behavior of your program :)